# Why does DrRacket load much faster on Ubuntu than on W10?

Tags: dual-boot, software-installation

I'm using a dualboot configuration with Ubuntu 20.04 and Windows 10.

While most applications load faster on Ubuntu, [DrRacket](https://racket-lang.org/) loads much faster, perhaps 2x, on Ubuntu compared to W10. I was wondering if anyone has an explanation for this performance difference?

I'm pleasantly surprised about it, just curious and willing to learn more about the reasons behind it.

Answer (score -1):

Linux is more optimized than Windows! Therefor making applications load faster! Your not the only one that was curious about this! :D